# Using Ast.Expressions to create a delegate

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, expression-trees

I'm experimenting with Expressions (Microsoft.Scripting.Ast) and need to assign a delegate variable with a delegate to another instance method and then call that delegate. Unfortunately I'm very clueless :(

```
var @delegate = Expression.Variable (typeof (Delegate));
var expression = Expression.Block(
     new [] { @delegate },
     Expression.Assign(@delegate, /* MISSED PART */),
     Expression.Call(@delegate, typeof(Delegate).GetMethod("DynamicInvoke"))
);
```

*Please tell me if I missed anything. This is for my lately started internship. So it is possible that it makes no sense at all ^^*

Comment: Well you're not using the result of the Block method, for a start...

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. _Btw, thanks for your book. It's right beside of me ;)_

Comment: Are you *really* using Microsoft.Scripting.Ast rather than the "normal" expression trees (System.Linq.Expressions), btw? If so, do you have any particular reason for doing so? (Glad you like the book, btw.) I don't have any experience of Microsoft.Scripting.Ast, but if you can provide a more complete example of what you're trying to do, I'll have a go with System.Linq.Expressions...

Comment: The project I'm going to support is using MS.Scripting.Ast.. The reason is quite simple - they need the additional stuff, linq expressions do not support (i.e., control flow, assignment, etc.). Sorry, but I cannot give a more detailed example, because I'm lacking of project skillz ;) I just need to create a delegate to an instance method, and then call it with a self defined set of arguments. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Are you using .NET 3.5? The stuff from Microsoft.Scripting.Ast was blended into System.Linq.Expressions in .NET 4, I believe...

Comment: Yes, I'm using NET 3.5. I'll add that as tag. Thanks

Comment: *planlos* does not translate to *planless* :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was `Expression.GetDelegateType(...)`

Here is a code snippet that creates a delegate for a `MethodInfo`:

```
public static Type GetDelegateType (this MethodInfo methodInfo)
{
  var parameterTypes = methodInfo.GetParameters ().Select (x => x.ParameterType);
  var returnType = new[] { methodInfo.ReturnType };

  var delegateTypes = parameterTypes.Concat (returnType).ToArray ();
  return Expression.GetDelegateType (delegateTypes);
}
```